# Regarding CoreData and relationship between 2 entities?

Tags: ios, core-data

Question is related to CoreData. I have created 2 entities in Coredata. One is DocumentReference and another is DocumentData.

DocumentReference contains below attributes:
id - Primary Key
docId - Reference of document Id in documentData Entity
name - Name of the document

DocumentData contains below attributes:
id - Primary Key
data - Actual content of the document.

DocumentReference can have reference of same document multiple times with only one entry in DocumentData Entity. Relationship for the same have also been created.

Issue which i am facing is that when i delete a DocumentReference, Document from DocumentData table should only be delete when there are no references of the document left in the DocumentReference table.

[image]

Comment: Add screen shot of graph diagram to better understand your question.

Comment: Yatheesha: Graph diagram added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You since the DocumentReference has a to-many relationship with DocumentData, you can check the count of the referenced documents which is a NSSet. Like this, where hasDocumentDatas is the to many relationship:

```
-(if DocumentReference.hasDocumentDatas.count <1){
   // Delete
}
else {
    NSLog(@"DocumentReference has still %d documents referenced",DocumentReference.hasDocumentDatas.count);
}
```

Comment: Can this be done using relationships and delete rule(cascade, Deny)?